# Usage of data source information in IIS

Tags: .net, web-config

This is a "best practice" question, but it concerns theoretical knowledge about how data sources are supposed to be handled under IIS. It mainly concerns IIS7, but I suspect the answer is not strictly related to this version.

IIS allows defining data sources, either via **IIS Manager > Features > Connection Strings** or directly into the **connectionStrings** section of the **web.config** file. These information mean the connection string but also the provider, so it looks like IIS is provided with all necessary information to connect to the data source. Therefore I would expect IIS to be able to do something with these information - namely to manage the data source connection process.

However, every code example I found so far only uses the (web.config) connection string to open the connection by its own means, and generally disregarding the provider set up in the configuration. This works but... it looks more like a workaround rather than the intended way of things.

So, finally my question: am I missing some data source management feature of IIS (and in this case, could anyone point me to the proper class reference or other documentation)?

Or are programs running under IIS actually supposed to open the data sources by themselves (and in this case, what is the point of defining the connection strings as "data sources" in IIS, while a simple "setting" could be used as well to hold a connection string)?

Thanks for any hint on this matter.

Comment: As far as I know the configuration feature in IIS is mainly to make it easier for IT administrators to configure the application (as opposed to having to modify the web.config file directly)

Comment: IIS Manager is able to show the information does not mean it is managed by IIS at all. That comes from `machine.config` and other .NET Framework bits, so it is purely a .NET question.

Answer (score 0):

(As > 1 month without getting an answer IS an answer to this kind of question, and after further researching into the matter, I am now able to answer it myself)

It seems that programs running under IIS actually ARE expected to manage the data sources by themselves, and moreover there are two distinct strategies to do so.

### The "generic" strategy

One approach is to consider the data source as being generic, without implying a certain type/provider (like SqlServer).

In this case, one should use the `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory` class to get (not open) the database connection as a `System.Data.Common.DbConnection` instance. In order to provide this connection, the factory class needs the connection string AND the (connection) provider ID. The factory class is responsible for instantiating the proper classes for that provider, by looking it up in the `machine.config` file (as pointed up above by Lex Li).

Here is where the dedicated `connectionStrings` section in `web.config` comes handy, because its content is not actually a "string" but a structure containing the connection string itself AND the provider identification, for instance:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="actual SqlServer connection string" name="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is the simplest code that follows this approach to get a database connection (stripped of all error handling, thus unusable as is):

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName];
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(config.providerName); 
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = config.ConnectionString;
```

That's not a lot of code to write, even when complete with error handling, and this is probably why there is no "standard" function within the IIS framework that takes a connection name and returns a connection. The piece of code above IS that function.

This approach is mandatory for application that are supposed to access various database types, unknown at design type. It is probably good practice, for flexibility considerations, even for applications that are supposed to use one particular database of a previously known type. However, in this case ALL data access should be designed to be generic (for instance, even if connecting to a SqlServer database, all data handling must use Db* classes not Sql* classes).

### The "specific" strategy

Another approach is to assume that a given database type would be ALWAYS used by the application. This is a less flexible approach but - as far as I could see - very popular due to its simplicity.

In this case, the connection can be obtained by instantiating the previously known class, for instance:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

In this approach there is no need  to look for a provider, or to have it declared in `machine.config`, because the connection class to instantiate is known at compile time.

Also, this approach does not require a fully-fledged `connectionStrings` section in `web.config`. Actually, having someone define the connection within the connection string section, like in the example above **while completely ignoring the database provider identification** is confusing and could be regarded as poor design.

As such, I consider perfectly acceptable that in this approach one does not use the `connectionStrings` section (of the `web.config` file) at all, instead one uses a simple "application setting" to hold the connection string. This way, everything that gets defined in `web.config` is actually used by the programs.